# Error occurring during compile time : error:program type already present: com.google.android.gms.measurement.appmeasurementinstallreferrerreceiver

Tags: android

I've been using Firebase messaging and databases for my project. Using different dependencies and and their specific versions, the program synced completely and there was no gradle build errors.

After connecting the debugging device and trying to install the apk, the error comes as following.

> error:program type already present:
>   com.google.android.gms.measurement.appmeasurementinstallreferrerreceiver

I am unable to proceed further and would really like a solution.I tried surfing the web but am unable to find one.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure whats causing the problem,but the gradle dependencies are the ones causing this error. Modifying my **build.gradle file** as follows

```
dependencies {
   implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
   // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES START
   implementation(project(path: "CordovaLib"))
   implementation "com.android.support:customtabs:26.+"
   implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1+"
   implementation "com.google.gms:google-services:+"
   implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager:11.0.4"
   implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.4"
   implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.4"
   implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.0.4"
   implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-config:11.0.4"
   implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:11.0.4"
   implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.0.4"
   implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:11.0.4"
   implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23+"
   // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES END
  }
```

solved that error for me